# Give an example with the following property:

Tags: calculus, functions

Give examples for functions, which are not differentiable at the point 0, but their multiplication is differentiable.

I still have no idea, how to find such functions, I know that the absolute value function is of course not differentiable at 0

Comment: $f(x):=|x|$, $g(x)=1/f(x)$ and $fg(x)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First example**

You know that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0.$ Does it happen the same to $$|x|\cdot |x|=x^2?$$

**Second example**

Consider $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}-1,& x\le 0\\ 1 ,&x>0.\end{cases}$ Note that $g$ is not even continuous at $0.$ But, what function is $f(x)g(x)?$